# How to fill a hashmap with an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

It kinda speaks for itself but how do I fill this?

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>intMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I've already tried

```
intMap.put(1, 2);
intMap.put(1, 3); etc
```

and

```
intMap.put(1, (2, 3);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
intMap.computeIfAbsent(someKey, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(someValue);
```

For example, to have these mappings:

```
1 -> [2, 3]
5 -> [8]
6 -> [7, 9, 4]
```

You could do it this way:

```
intMap.computeIfAbsent(1, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(2);
intMap.computeIfAbsent(1, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(3);

intMap.computeIfAbsent(5, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(8);

intMap.computeIfAbsent(6, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(7);
intMap.computeIfAbsent(6, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(9);
intMap.computeIfAbsent(6, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(4);
```

---

**EDIT:**

`Map.computeIfAbsent` is equivalent to this code:

```
List<Integer> list = intMap.get(someKey);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    intMap.put(someKey, list);
}
list.add(someValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
intMap.put(1, list);

list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(4);
list.add(5);
list.add(6);
intMap.put(2, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't map to ArrayList.  When using lists, never mention more specific than List except in the one place you construct it.  There's no reason your map shouldn't accept a different type of List.  (Also, if the order doesn't matter, it should just be a Collection, not a List.  Declare things to be the least specific you can.)

The post above about using computeIfAbsent is the right answer while you are working with the map.  If you're just trying to initialize the map with a few values, you could do this.

```
map.put(1, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,3)));
map.put(2, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7, 9, 11)));
```

(Corrected as per the excellent comment below.)

Comment: Careful with this approach. `Arrays.asList` doesn't allow to add elements to the list later. Maybe you could use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))`. Agreed with all your other comments +1

Answer (score 1):

If the map and the lists are not modifiable once instantiated, with Java 9 you could do :

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = Map.of(1, List.of(2, 3), 
                                         2, List.of(3, 5));
```

If the Map and the lists are modifiable, you could follow the approach of Federico Peralta Schaffner and makes it a little more user friendly by extracting a method with var-args :

```
void fill(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map, Integer key, Integer... values) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>())
       .addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
}
```

You can use it now easily :

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
fill(map, 1, 2, 3);
fill(map, 2, 4, 6);
fill(map, 2, 1);
```

Beware, passing a `null` reference in the var-args will trigger a `NullPointerException` in `Arrays.asList(values)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can try in  multiple ways like,

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>intMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();

intMap.put(101,new ArrayList<Integer>().add(1));
intMap.put(102,new ArrayList<Integer>().add(2));
```

I guess If you have multiple values per single index then only you are trying for this, In that case we can do like this,

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(2);
...

ArrayList<Integer> list2=new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(1);
list2.add(2);
...
```

Then,

```
intMap.put(1,list1);
intMap.put(2,list2);
```